# GraphQL query with flexible type

Tags: database, graphql

I want to know if it is possible to query data from multiple database tables with GraphQL. The tricky thing behind this is that the table columns can vary (because the users can edit them). So, is it possible to have something like a "flexible graphql query" which is flexible to the table columns?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: column name can be a field param, you can query a single `someAliasForOneOfManyFields: value(id:"someID", column:"tableName.someColumn")` - `value` resolver should do the rest .... do you really need a "raw"/SQL-ish data modeling? no abstraction? EAV?, search for 'dynamic graphql schema'

Comment: Thanks, I will research on that.
I have only considered using raw SQL data modeling yet.